# Is there any solution in VIM for bookmarking files or directories other than NERDTree?

Tags: vim

I am migrating from Emacs to VIM recently. Files and dirs bookmarking function is my favorite function of Emacs, as following:

Ctrl-x r l: List bookmarks
Ctrl-x r b: Goto the bookmark's destionation
Ctrl-x r m: Add a bookmark

In VIM I found two solutions: NERDTree and netrw

netrw's bookmark function can not set bookmark's name, can not visit or delete via bookmark's name.

NERDTree can do all of this.

Is there any other solution to this problem other than NERDTree?

Comment: why not just use NERDTree if it met all your needs?

Answer (score 0):

There some solutions using vim plugins other than the *great* NerdTree:

- Using `cdargs` inside vim with the plugin: [vim-cdargs](https://github.com/gaffneyc/vim-cdargs)
- Use the [cmdalias plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) to map custom commands to enter into bookmarked diretories